# phpexcel line chart not taking cell value

Tags: phpexcel

i am using php excel to generate chart, but its not taking cell value. for reference you can refer http://uvresins.net/images/xls.png

My chart variable return :

PHPExcel_Chart Object
(

```
[_name:PHPExcel_Chart:private] => chart1
[_worksheet:PHPExcel_Chart:private] => 
[_title:PHPExcel_Chart:private] => PHPExcel_Chart_Title Object
    (
        [_caption:PHPExcel_Chart_Title:private] => Scgcc
        [_layout:PHPExcel_Chart_Title:private] => 
    )

[_legend:PHPExcel_Chart:private] => PHPExcel_Chart_Legend Object
    (
        [_position:PHPExcel_Chart_Legend:private] => tr
        [_overlay:PHPExcel_Chart_Legend:private] => 
        [_layout:PHPExcel_Chart_Legend:private] => 
    )

[_xAxisLabel:PHPExcel_Chart:private] => 
[_yAxisLabel:PHPExcel_Chart:private] => PHPExcel_Chart_Title Object
    (
        [_caption:PHPExcel_Chart_Title:private] => Value ($k)
        [_layout:PHPExcel_Chart_Title:private] => 
    )

[_plotArea:PHPExcel_Chart:private] => PHPExcel_Chart_PlotArea Object
    (
        [_layout:PHPExcel_Chart_PlotArea:private] => 
        [_plotSeries:PHPExcel_Chart_PlotArea:private] => Array
            (
                [0] => PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries Object
                    (
                        [_plotType:PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries:private] => lineChart
                        [_plotGrouping:PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries:private] => stacked
                        [_plotDirection:PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries:private] => 
                        [_plotStyle:PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries:private] => 
                        [_plotOrder:PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries:private] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => 0
                                [1] => 1
                                [2] => 2
                            )

                        [_plotLabel:PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries:private] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues Object
                                    (
                                        [_dataType:PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues:private] => String
                                        [_dataSource:PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues:private] => Worksheet!$B$1
                                        [_formatCode:PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues:private] => 
                                        [_marker:PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues:private] => 
                                        [_pointCount:PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues:private] => 1
                                        [_dataValues:PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues:private] => Array
                                            (
                                            )

                                    )

                                [1] => PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues Object
                                    (
                                        [_dataType:PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues:private] => String
                                        [_dataSource:PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues:private] => Worksheet!$C$1
                                        [_formatCode:PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues:private] => 
                                        [_marker:PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues:private] => 
                                        [_pointCount:PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues:private] => 1
                                        [_dataValues:PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues:private] => Array
                                            (
                                            )

                                    )

                                [2] => PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues Object
                                    (
                                        [_dataType:PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues:private] => String
                                        [_dataSource:PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues:private] => Worksheet!$D$1
                                        [_formatCode:PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues:private] => 
                                        [_marker:PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues:private] => 
                                        [_pointCount:PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues:private] => 1
                                        [_dataValues:PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues:private] => Array
                                            (
                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                        [_plotCategory:PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries:private] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues Object
                                    (
                                        [_dataType:PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues:private] => String
                                        [_dataSource:PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues:private] => Worksheet!$A$2:$A$6
                                        [_formatCode:PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues:private] => 
                                        [_marker:PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues:private] => 
                                        [_pointCount:PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues:private] => 5
                                        [_dataValues:PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues:private] => Array
                                            (
                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                        [_smoothLine:PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries:private] => 
                        [_plotValues:PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries:private] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues Object
                                    (
                                        [_dataType:PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues:private] => Number
                                        [_dataSource:PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues:private] => Worksheet!$B$2:$B$6
                                        [_formatCode:PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues:private] => 
                                        [_marker:PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues:private] => 
                                        [_pointCount:PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues:private] => 5
                                        [_dataValues:PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues:private] => Array
                                            (
                                            )

                                    )

                                [1] => PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues Object
                                    (
                                        [_dataType:PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues:private] => Number
                                        [_dataSource:PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues:private] => Worksheet!$C$2:$C$6
                                        [_formatCode:PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues:private] => 
                                        [_marker:PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues:private] => 
                                        [_pointCount:PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues:private] => 5
                                        [_dataValues:PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues:private] => Array
                                            (
                                            )

                                    )

                                [2] => PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues Object
                                    (
                                        [_dataType:PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues:private] => Number
                                        [_dataSource:PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues:private] => Worksheet!$D$2:$D$6
                                        [_formatCode:PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues:private] => 
                                        [_marker:PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues:private] => 
                                        [_pointCount:PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues:private] => 5
                                        [_dataValues:PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues:private] => Array
                                            (
                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                    )

            )

    )

[_plotVisibleOnly:PHPExcel_Chart:private] => 1
[_displayBlanksAs:PHPExcel_Chart:private] => 0
[_topLeftCellRef:PHPExcel_Chart:private] => A13
[_topLeftXOffset:PHPExcel_Chart:private] => 0
[_topLeftYOffset:PHPExcel_Chart:private] => 0
[_bottomRightCellRef:PHPExcel_Chart:private] => H30
[_bottomRightXOffset:PHPExcel_Chart:private] => 10
[_bottomRightYOffset:PHPExcel_Chart:private] => 10
```

)

AND FromArray has value :

Array
(

[0] => Array
        (

```
        [0] => 

        [1] => 12/2011

        [2] => 01/2012

        [3] => 02/2012
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => QATAR
        [1] => 102.77
        [2] => 100
        [3] => 102.13
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => SAUDI ARABIA
        [1] => 102.74
        [2] => 100
        [3] => 98.22
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => KUWAIT
        [1] => 94.82
        [2] => 100
        [3] => 102.28
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [0] => U.A.E.
        [1] => 101.22
        [2] => 100
        [3] => 99.94
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [0] => OMAN
        [1] => 101.73
        [2] => 100
        [3] => 100.42
    )
```

)

Please tell me whats going wrong from my side, if nothing then y graph not appearing.

Comment: can any one reply please